# Access 2007 VBA Record Set Infinite Loop

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I am doing a query that when you click a button it takes a record set with an unassigned field of data and copies that recordset into the same table with a new "assigned version".

I want my database to be able to make different/multiple "assigned versions" from the original unassigned set, and this works great when i create the first assigned set, but  when i try to create a new assigned set it goes into a loop that seems completely random, it could create new entries from 10-1000 and i dont know what is causing this.

Sorry if this was confusing, looking at the code will probably help more

thanks!

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
 Dim unionquery As String

 Dim CURRENT_SOFTWARE_VERSION As String

 CURRENT_SOFTWARE_VERSION = Me.Parent.[Software Version].Value

 initialquery = "select [Test Script] , [PROC_CHECK_ID], [Software Version] from (FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS inner join FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_CHECK on FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.TEST_CASE_ID = FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_CHECK.TEST_CASE_ID) inner join FORMAL_CERT_SOFTWARE_VERSION on FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.TEST_CASE_ID = FORMAL_CERT_SOFTWARE_VERSION.TEST_CASE_ID where PROC_CHECK_ID=" & Me.PROC_CHECK_ID & " AND [Software Version]=""" & CURRENT_SOFTWARE_VERSION & """ "

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(initialquery, dbOpenForwardOnly)

    Do Until rs1.EOF = True

        Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
                  "SELECT * FROM FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS", _
                  dbOpenDynaset)
        rs2.AddNew
        rs2![Test Script] = rs1![Test Script]
        rs2![PROC_CHECK_ID_FK] = rs1!PROC_CHECK_ID
        rs2![Software_Version] = rs1![Software Version].Value
        rs2![TEST_CASE_ID] = Me.TEST_CASE_ID
        rs2.Update
        rs2.Close
        Set rs2 = Nothing

        rs1.MoveNext

    Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear.
If you add records into the table you are currently iterating through, you will have problems in reaching EOF, since you are not only iterating through what you started with, but also the new records that you just added.

The solution is to separate the loop and the insert into discrete steps: loop through and save the values you want to insert, then insert after the loop is finished.
Assuming the values are string, numeric, string, numeric:

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(initialquery, dbOpenForwardOnly)
dim strQuery() as String
dim intCounter as Long
dim recordCount as Long
intCounter = 0
rs1.MoveLast
recordCount = rs1.RecordCount
Redim strQuery(0 to recordCount)
rs1.MoveFirst
strQuery(0) = "INSERT INTO FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS ([Test Script],[PROC_CHECK_ID_FK],[Software_Version],[TEST_CASE_ID]) VALUES "
Do Until rs1.EOF = True
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
    strQuery(intCounter) = strQuery(0) & " ('" & rs1![Test Script] & "'," & _
        & rs1!PROC_CHECK_ID & "," & _
        & "'" & rs1![Software Version].Value & "'," & _
        & Me.TEST_CASE_ID & ")"
    rs1.MoveNext

Loop

For intCounter = 0 To recordCount
    CurrentDb.Execute(strQuery(intCounter))
Next
```

This will avoid the issue of the EOF pointer moving further away as you insert.

Edit: I forgot you can't do multiple inserts with default DBA, I changed the code to reflect that.